# Use C# to write ASP code on a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ext.net

I have ASP code like this:

```
<ext:Panel ID="pnlHelp" CtCls="help-panel" AnimCollapse="true"">
    <Content>
        <h1>some text</h1>
        <p>
            More text[...]
        </p>
    </Content>
</ext:Panel>
```

I would like to generate the `<Content>` tag dynamically using C#. I tried this, like with regular HTML tags:

```
<ext:Panel ID="pnlHelp" CtCls="help-panel" AnimCollapse="true"">
    <Content>
        <% Response.Write("<h1>some text</h1>"); %>                             
        <p>
            More text[...]
        </p>
    </Content>
</ext:Panel>
```

But the text ends up somewhere near the beginning of the page where I didn't intend it to go. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You output appears on the top of the page because your `Response.Write()` is being executed before page content is put to respose.

Why [not just](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5%28VS.71%29.aspx)

```
<%="<h1>some text</h1>" %>
```

You can create a method that will return a string and call it from your `*.as?x` file:

```
protected string GetMyCoolHtml()
{
    return "<h3>this is my text</h3>";
}

....

<%= GetMyCoolHtml() %>
```

Comment: It worked for the static phrase. But then I put in `<%= GetPhrase("some_text_key", "<h1>some text</h1>"); %>` and I'm getting a " ) expected" error. Why's that?

Comment: check the signature of you method. you code works for me when methoв is decalared as `protected string GetPhrase(string key, string h1Text) { return key + "<br />" + h1Text;  }`

Comment: Remove the ';'. When using <%= %> for displaying things, no ; is expected.

Comment: oh, sure +1 to @Abbas comment :)

Comment: Okay, this works. What's the name of this inline code tag so I can read more about it?

Answer (score 1):

Add a literal control to your page and write whatever you want on server side.